# XSLT date comparrison in VBA

Tags: vba, xslt, xslt-1.0

Due to restrictions I'm unable to use version 2.0 or any packages. I'm currently using VBA to call this XSL template and in turn filter out the dates prior to 20120101 (YYYYMMDD).

I would like to essentially filter all  which have a  greater date than the given variable date

```
'<xsl:template match=""BankStatementItemDetail[//BankStatementItemDetail[number(concat(substring(TransactionDate, 1, 4 ),substring( TransactionDate, 6, 2 ),substring( TransactionDate, 9, 2 ))) <= "" year & month & day ""  ]]"">`
```

TransactionDate format 2012-06-22T00:00:00
year month day format 20120101

And example of the xml structure

```
<BankStatementItemDetail Key="e744f079-c684-4567-b844-5442e69a1827">
    <Id>https:///xxx/components/x/bank-statement-item/e744f079-c084-7567-b844-5b42569a1827</Id>
    <Version>1</Version>
    <EffectiveStatus>Active</EffectiveStatus>
    <EffectiveStatusDateTime>2012-06-23T07:34:45</EffectiveStatusDateTime>
    <SecurityDescriptor>
        <IsEditable>true</IsEditable>
    </SecurityDescriptor>
    <account Code="xxxx" ScopeCode="xxxx" Uid="a0f60cd9-25a0-4955-a55c-2dc73bb0dd51">
        <Id>https://test/components/administration/account/a0f40cd9-23a0-4955-a55c-2dc73bb0dd51</Id>
        <Description>Trial Account</Description>
    </account>
</BankStatementItemDetail>
```

Comment: I assume that what you're trying isn't working, but maybe you could edit your question to add some more detail, such as what the error you're getting is, or what your output is?  Also, an example of the XML you're applying this to would be useful.

Comment: When I run     //BankStatementItemDetail[//BankStatementItemDetail[number (concat(substring( TransactionDate, 1, 4 ),substring( TransactionDate, 6, 2 ),substring( TransactionDate, 9, 2 ))) <= 20120202 ]] 
in my text editor and evaluate the xpath expression it seems to return values but when I run the above xslt template in vba it returns a run-time error. The stylesheet does not contain a document element. The stylesheet may be empty or may not be a well-formed XML document.

Comment: "Where TransactionDate, and year, month, day are my two date variables." This sentence doesn't make any sense. Please clarify.

Comment: What is your XSLT processor? Does it support EXSLT?

Comment: Currently EXSLT is not an option.

Comment: So, what is the wanted result? This question is really confusing -- do you want to gett all dates *greater* that a given date, or all dates *prior* a given date? Which one of these two options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This simple transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "BankStatementItemDetail
   [20120101000000
   >
    translate(EffectiveStatusDateTime, '-:T', '')
   ]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document** (based on the provided one but with two `BankStatementItemDetail` elements, the second of which is prior to 2012-01-01):

```
<details>
    <BankStatementItemDetail Key="e744f079-c684-4567-b844-5442e69a1827">
        <Id>https:///xxx/components/x/bank-statement-item/e744f079-c084-7567-b844-5b42569a1827</Id>
        <Version>1</Version>
        <EffectiveStatus>Active</EffectiveStatus>
        <EffectiveStatusDateTime>2012-06-23T07:34:45</EffectiveStatusDateTime>
        <SecurityDescriptor>
            <IsEditable>true</IsEditable>
        </SecurityDescriptor>
        <account Code="xxxx" ScopeCode="xxxx" Uid="a0f60cd9-25a0-4955-a55c-2dc73bb0dd51">
            <Id>https://test/components/administration/account/a0f40cd9-23a0-4955-a55c-2dc73bb0dd51</Id>
            <Description>Trial Account</Description>
        </account>
    </BankStatementItemDetail>
    <BankStatementItemDetail Key="e744f079-c684-4567-b844-5442e69a1827">
        <Id>https:///xxx/components/x/bank-statement-item/e744f079-c084-7567-b844-5b42569a1827</Id>
        <Version>1</Version>
        <EffectiveStatus>Active</EffectiveStatus>
        <EffectiveStatusDateTime>2011-12-31T08:39:52</EffectiveStatusDateTime>
        <SecurityDescriptor>
            <IsEditable>true</IsEditable>
        </SecurityDescriptor>
        <account Code="xxxx" ScopeCode="xxxx" Uid="a0f60cd9-25a0-4955-a55c-2dc73bb0dd51">
            <Id>https://test/components/administration/account/a0f40cd9-23a0-4955-a55c-2dc73bb0dd51</Id>
            <Description>Trial Account</Description>
        </account>
    </BankStatementItemDetail>
</details>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result** (the prior to 2012-01-01 `BankStatementItemDetail` has been "deleted"):

```
<details>
   <BankStatementItemDetail Key="e744f079-c684-4567-b844-5442e69a1827">
      <Id>https:///xxx/components/x/bank-statement-item/e744f079-c084-7567-b844-5b42569a1827</Id>
      <Version>1</Version>
      <EffectiveStatus>Active</EffectiveStatus>
      <EffectiveStatusDateTime>2012-06-23T07:34:45</EffectiveStatusDateTime>
      <SecurityDescriptor>
         <IsEditable>true</IsEditable>
      </SecurityDescriptor>
      <account Code="xxxx" ScopeCode="xxxx" Uid="a0f60cd9-25a0-4955-a55c-2dc73bb0dd51">
         <Id>https://test/components/administration/account/a0f40cd9-23a0-4955-a55c-2dc73bb0dd51</Id>
         <Description>Trial Account</Description>
      </account>
   </BankStatementItemDetail>
</details>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the substring() function and implicit type-casting. For example, this XSLT 1.0 style-sheet...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="ref-year" select="2012" />
<xsl:variable name="ref-mon"  select="6" />
<xsl:variable name="ref-day"  select="23" />

<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="BankStatementItemDetail[
      ((substring( EffectiveStatusDateTime, 1, 4) * 416) +
       (substring( EffectiveStatusDateTime, 6, 2) *  32) +
       (substring( EffectiveStatusDateTime, 9, 2)      )) >=
      (($ref-year * 416) + ($ref-mon * 32) + $ref-day)
    ]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...when applied to this input...

```
<BankStatementItems>
  <BankStatementItemDetail id="1">
    <EffectiveStatusDateTime>2012-06-23T07:34:45</EffectiveStatusDateTime>
  </BankStatementItemDetail>
  <BankStatementItemDetail id="2">
    <EffectiveStatusDateTime>2011-09-20</EffectiveStatusDateTime>
  </BankStatementItemDetail>
</BankStatementItems>
```

...yields...

```
<BankStatementItems>
  <BankStatementItemDetail id="1">
    <EffectiveStatusDateTime>2012-06-23T07:34:45</EffectiveStatusDateTime>
  </BankStatementItemDetail>
</BankStatementItems>
```

Comment: Can you please explain the 416 and the 32?

Comment: Maximum days in a month is 31, so 32*month ensures validity of month/day comparison. Maximum Months in a year = 12, so 13*32 ensures validity of year/month/day comparison. I concede it's a little obtuse. Dimitre's method seems clearer and more readable.